# Is there a way to redirect a route inside group route?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Let's say I had this routes config:

```
pages

 - index.vue
 - admin
  - login.vue
  - register.vue
```

Is there a way to make `/admin/login` act as the index of admin routes? I want to simply redirect whoever hits `/admin` to `/admin/login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/#anonymous-middleware) in `/admin/index.vue`, which has a [`redirect`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-redirect-code-em-function-em-) method in its `context` argument:

```html
<script>
export default {
  middleware({ redirect }) {
    redirect(301, '/admin/login')
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: is there any guide on the official docs for further reading? I'm not good at search keywords

Comment: hey @tony19 could you take a look at my new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332813/how-to-assign-a-middleware-to-specific-group-of-routes)

Answer (score 1):

The `vue-router` supports redirect in the route definitions:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect

```
const routes = [
  /* ... */
  { path: '/admin', redirect: '/admin/login' },
  { path: '/admin/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '/admin/register', name: 'Register', component: RegisterComponent },
]
```

You can also define nested routes like so:

```
const routes = [
  /* ... */
  {
    path: '/admin',
    redirect: '/admin/login',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        name: 'Register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I think this answer might need to describe how to use this config in a Nuxt project.